# Can I disable the hardware 'Search' button?

Tags: hardware, buttons, search

I'm teaching my 85 year old mother to use her first phone. Her first ever bit of computing. The first use is texting and I've removed all the apps from the main screens except for the messaging app, and after a few days of casual instruction she's now texting and replying to texts very well.

I've only taught her two other buttons so far:

Home (she insists on calling it the 'Hut' button so if I call it the 'Hut' button she knows what I mean).

Back/Undo button

If she gets into something that she doesn't understand her instructions are to hit 'Hut' or 'Undo' and that will cure most things.

However she still gets caught out pressing the search button which brings up 'the internet' and that's currently really confusing, too much for her to handle :-)

This is a Samsung I5503T so has a physical 'Search' button on the lower right. It's right beside the undo/back button so gets hit by mistake (a lot). Is there any way to disable the physical 'Search' button or reassign it so it does nothing.

I'll eventually add more apps but starting slowly (since I live in a different town so most support is by landline phone :-(

Answer (score 1):

It is very late to answer this now but just to remove it from the "Unanswered Questions Section"

You can use these light weight apps:

1. [Remap buttons and gestures](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sumyapplications.button.remapper&hl=en&gl=US)
2. [Button Mapper: Remap your keys](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=flar2.homebutton&hl=en&gl=US)